# getting 404 with $.getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying use $.getJSON (jquery 2) to call a web service at:

```
http://localhost:8080/ws/family/1
```

This web service works when I type it into a browser.  I am using the Jetty Maven plugin so there is no context root.   My page resides at:

```
http://localhost:8080/view/index.html
```

Here is my javascript (Edited):

```
var getFamily = function() {
        return $.getJSON({
            url: "/ws/family/1"
        });
    };
```

I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/view/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
```

I do not have a base tag in my page.

Comment: So basically the server is telling you that there is *nothing* on that URL, as in "Not Found", and the URL is posted right there, with a big `[object%20Object]` in it, and you're wondering what is wrong with your javascript ?

Comment: Looks like your `familyId` is an object, not a plain string value. And the slash after `/ws/family` seems to be missing as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike e.g. `$.ajax` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)), `$.getJSON` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)) doesn't expect an object as a parameter - it expects the URL as a string - for example:

```
return $.getJSON("/ws/family" + familyId); // Correct
```

Since you're passing an object:

```
return $.getJSON( { url: "/ws/family" + familyId } ); // Wrong
```

... Javascript will convert all of it to a string, yielding the standard result of `object.toString()` : "[object Object]".

Which means your call amounts to:

```
return $.getJSON("[object Object]");
```

Which is why your request goes to:

http://localhost:8080/view/[object%20Object]

Comment: I changed the URL to "/ws/family/1".  Same result.  The web service works.  I can type http://localhost:8080/ws/family/1 into a browser and get a response

Comment: You'll always get the same result as long as you're passing an object to $.getJSON rather than a string - no matter what string you put inside the object, the end result will be "[object Object]". See comparison in the edited answer. @Daedalus: Fixed, thanks. :-)

Comment: I am not passing anything now.  I changed my url to "/ws/family/1"

Comment: @badgerduke Show us what you're currently trying.

Comment: var getFamily = function() {
  return $.getJSON({
   url: "/ws/family/1"
  });
 };

Comment: @badgerduke Then you're still doing it wrong; read this answer again, and read it slowly.

Comment: You're still passing an object - `{ url: "..." }` creates an object with a `url` property. You need to pass a normal string. See comparison (`//Wrong` vs. `//Correct`) again.